# OPNET: wrote a function in process model of opnet but has error

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, return-value

I'm simulating a network protocol with opnet. in process model for a process block I wrote this function in FB. But when compiling it, gives me:

```
error: function 'inrpt_timer' must return a value;
```

but it is returning 'intrpt'. I'm confused! also another question: I don't know why I should put static at first of function definition. I just putted it because predefined functions also had it. maybe the problem is with that! here is the code:

```
static int intrpt_timer()
{
int intrpt;

FIN(intrpt_timer());

if((op_sim_time()-last_time)>=Ts)   //check for interrupt
    {
    intrpt=1;//1 is true
    last_time=op_sim_time();        //if timer passed update last time value
    }
else
    intrpt=0;//zero is false


return intrpt;  
FOUT;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

haha, found it myself;

when want to return a value, (in opnet) "FRET(value);"  replaces  "return value;"

Answer (score 0):

`I don't know why I should put static at first of function definition.`

A function being declared `static` means it can only be called from current compilation unit.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `FIN(...);` in your code, you must either use `FOUT;` or `FRET(...)` to close the function, depending on whether the function should return anything.

`FOUT;` for `void func(...)`
`FRET(...);` for `int/double/Boolean... func(...)`